# Iterate over array content without knowing the keys values

Tags: symfony, twig

Can someone tell me how to iterate over array keys without knowing their values ? 
For example:

```
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "AccountId"
  "activated" => "false"
  "type" => "string"
]
```

I'd like to get a select list with:

```
<select name="select">
  <option>name: AccountId</option>
  <option>activated: false</option>
  <option>type: string</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Iterating over Keys and Values as described in the [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values), as example:

```
<select name="select">
    {% for key, value in users %}
       < option > {{ key }}: {{ value }}</option >
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! can you please tell me about this error  ? 
Key "key" doesn't exist ? why it doesn't take the value of key instead of "key"

    <select name="select">
     {% for key,value in array %}
       {% if (key !=  'id') and (key != 'type') %}
         <option value={{key}}>{{ array.key }}</option>
       {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
    </select>

Comment: uhmm seems due to the `{{ array.key }}` try with `{{ value }}` as described in the provided answer

Comment: Well actually your answer helped me to write the for loop but in my page 'value' is an array so I thought that I could access to its attributes by the doing value.key but it doesn't work when it dynamically ( if i do value.type it works )

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<select>
    {% for key, value in data %}
        <option>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

You can read more about [for loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) in Twig's documentation.